# How to make a query parameter

Tags: javascript, express, pug

Build a dynamic website using Node.js with Express.js and Pug.js. For this assignment, pick a country and build a brochure website (ie a one page website with information), all facts listed on the page can be made up and the content needs to be G or PG. This website will change based on the system time of the machine running Node.js. If the user views the page from 7 am to 7 pm (inclusive), the page should have a CSS and look based around day. The facts about that country should be day oriented. If the page is viewed outside of 7 am to 7 pm, the facts and CSS theme should change to be night oriented. The majority of the page’s look and information should change based on being day or night.

Also, your page must accept a query parameter called “hour” that will instead use that time instead of the system time. The hour must be able to be input as military time (ie 1 is 1 am and 13 is 1 pm).

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express'),
app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', 'views');
app.use(express.static('resources'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    let date = new Date();
    let time = date.getHours(); 
    if (time >= 7 && time <= 18) {
        res.render('day');
    }
    else {
        res.render('night');
    }
});
app.get('/hour', function(req, res){
    const hour = req.query.hour;
    if(hour >=7 && hour <= 19){
        res.render('day');
    }
    else {
        res.render('night');
    }
});
const server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log(`Server started on port ${server.address().port}`);   
});
```

Above is a copy of my code with the pug files being named 'day' and 'night'. I have pretty much completed this assignment, but am having one issue that I cannot seem to figure out. The base path for the page is `localhost:3000/` and the base path with the query parameter, `hour`, is supposed to be `localhost:3000/?hour=(hour)`. The only way I can get the program to run correctly is by using the path `localhost:3000/hour?hour=(hour)`. What is a good way to write this so I can get the expected results with using the path of `localhost:3000/?hour=(hour)`?

Comment: Can't you just use `req.query.some_param`? So `localhost:3000?hour=7` would come through any route via `req.query.hour`... Souce: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `/hour` route, and just get the query parameter in the `/` route. If the parameter isn't supplied, use the current time as the default.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    let hour = req.query.hour;
    if (hour) {
        hour = parseInt(hour);
    } else {
        let date = new Date();
        hour = date.getHours(); 
    }
    if (hour >= 7 && hour <= 18) {
        res.render('day');
    }
    else {
        res.render('night');
    }
});
```

Comment: Where does the `.date.` part of this come from?? Shouldn't it be `req.params.hour`? Oh - you got it, `.query.`

Comment: That was a typo, I meant `req.query.hour`, just as in the original function.